# Visual Studio Code: Python Linting: Warning if import method from file that does not exist

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, static-analysis

Is it possible to get Visual Studio Code to give a warning if a method which does not exist has been imported from a file?

So in the example below, I would like if the editor would warn that there is no `fun2` method in the file `utilities.py`

```py
# File called `utilities.py`
def fun1(a, b):
    return a+b
```

```py
from utility import fun1, fun2

temp1 = fun1(1,2)
temp2 = fun2(1,2)
```

In VS Code, I can see a difference in colours in the two functions, so it seems to know that it is not available:

[image]

Comment: So you already get a visual feedback? I'm confused

Comment: Do you have any linters installed? What about the standard Python extension package with pylance?

Comment: `mypy` linter will give warnings about missing attribute

Comment: The "warning" you get is a slight difference in colour which is hard to see in a large file. It is obviously detecting something. Is there a way to change this to an underline  type warning, or at least change colour so that it is more easily detected.

Comment: @Quimby: Pylance is installed and enabled

Comment: What if you run the code? Does it show you the `ImportError`?

Comment: @Coderio: Yes get `ImportError: cannot import name 'fun2' from 'utilities'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Methods one:

Add the following configuration in **settings.json** to enable linting and set linter to `pylint`

```json
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
```

You will get  error: `No name 'fun2' in module 'utility' pylint(no-name-in-module)`
[image]

##### Methods two:

Change **python.analysis.typeCheckingMode** to ***basic*** or ***strict*** in settings
[image]

*You can also add the following directly to the set*

```json
    "python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "strict",
```

This will give error hints by **pylance**
[image]

***The underscore warning appears both ways***
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I see this when I use flake8 using as my linter, it's great for pep8 but doesn't catch this type of issue. To fix that I use [mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to compliment flake8 with static type checking which will flag if an import doesn't exist. Once you've added mypy to your environment, add the following setting to VSCode:

```
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,     
    "python.linting.mypyEnabled": true,
```